# Triggered send duplication query?

Tags: automation, duplicate-management, automationstudio

I have setup an EnhancedFTP triggered automation.

In the automation studio it looks like this as I'm using 4 filter's to send 4 different variations of an email.

[image: Journey flow]

My problem is:

I only want to send to the records that are uploaded on the file I drop in daily.

At the moment it is adding new records to the list and apending new data to the contacts that are currently in the list, then filtering and sending all emails that match the filter query. So essentially sending the whole file everytime it runs.

How do I set it up so that it will only ever send the data uploaded on the day I drop the file on the EnhancedFTP.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Graeme

Answer (score 0):

After much testing we have found that creating a SQL query and data extension  that exclude's any member in a list that has a sent date works perfectly.

It doe's mean that for each of my 4 emails I would need a separate list however with unsubscribes shared across lists.

The SQL query looks like this:

SELECT a.EmailAddress as EmailAddress, a.SubscriberKey as SubscriberKey FROM _ListSubscribers a LEFT JOIN _Sent b ON a.ListID = b.ListId AND a.SubscriberID = b.SubscriberID WHERE a.ListId = 14211 AND b.SubscriberID is not null GROUP BY a.SubscriberKey, a.EmailAddress

Hope this helps, if anyone wants any clarification feel free to ask.